# mapping between xamarin form view model and back-end response

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

i was following eShopOnContainer project here at

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

while going through the code i observed that ProfileViewModel on Xamarin side whe initilizes, it makes a backend call

```
  var orders = await _orderService.GetOrdersAsync(authToken);
```

return type of GetOrdersAsync is Models.Orders.Order which has many properties but Ordering.API.Controllers has a GetOrders function (which i assume is called in this case)

```
[Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<OrderSummary>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetOrders()
    {
        var orders = await _orderQueries.GetOrdersAsync();

        return Ok(orders);
    }
```

has a return type of OrderSummary which have just 4 properties that are required by ProfileView.xaml

*My question is how is OrderSummary being mapped into Order.*

further more GetOrdersAsync calls generic GetAsync function that looks like as below.

```
   public async Task < TResult > GetAsync < TResult > (string uri, string token = "") {
HttpClient httpClient = CreateHttpClient(token);
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

await HandleResponse(response);
string serialized = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

TResult result = await Task.Run(() =>
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < TResult > (serialized, _serializerSettings));

return result;   }
```

The code works. Just trying to understand how.

Comment: Its working need to understand how

Comment: Please update your post to make that clearer. Perhaps a summary heading in bold at the start which says 'This code works, but I am hoping you can help me understand why it works.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers), I can see that:

- classes **'Order' & 'OrderSummary' share the same properties** with same names ('OrderSummary' contains less properties than 'Order')

  ```
  public class Order
  {
      public int ordernumber { get; set; }
      public DateTime date { get; set; }
      public string status { get; set; }
      public string description { get; set; }
      public string street { get; set; }
      public string city { get; set; }
      public string zipcode { get; set; }
      public string country { get; set; }
      public List<Orderitem> orderitems { get; set; }
      public decimal total { get; set; }
  }

  public class OrderSummary
  {
      public int ordernumber { get; set; }
      public DateTime date { get; set; }
      public string status { get; set; }
      public double total { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- The generic 'GetAsync( )' method deserialize **a string (JSON string)** into the desired object. That means that JSON deserializer try to match the property string names coming from the server to match with the properties of the TARGET type (generic Type).
- As all properties of 'OrderSummary' exist also into 'Order' classes, you can "map" a JSON 'OrderSummary' object into an 'Order' instance. All missing property values of 'Order' will be let to their default value.

**The key point is that your 'OrderSummary' (coming from the server) is in reality just a string.** **There is no mandatory typing when deserializing the json string.** Therefore, you could map an 'OrderSummary' object into all classes that contain at less the same properties (with a public setter).

Hope it's clear.